# passing paramters from visualforce emailtemplate to vf component not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="test" recipientType="Lead" relatedToType="Lead">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

<c:getLeadInfo LeadId="{!RelatedTo.Id}"/>


</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

vf component

```
<apex:component controller="LeadInfocon" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="LeadId" 
                    type="id" required="required" assignTo="{!leadVarId}" description="To get the lead id from template"/>

    <apex:outputText value="{!leadVarId}"></apex:outputText>

    Hi {!leadinfo.lead__r.name}, 

    You were recently on realtor.com and saw a property that you were looking to get some information on {!leadinfo.Street_Address__c} ADDRESS, {!leadinfo.City__c} .it is the four plex property. I have a team of agents here in our Fresno office and any one of them would be happy to assist you and answer any questions may have along the journey to your new home. Feel free to give me a call so that I can connect you to them, my direct line is 559-517-3436. 

    Thanks {!leadinfo.lead__r.name}
    Have a good day.
</apex:component>
```

controller for component

```
public with sharing class LeadInfocon {

    public LeadInfo__c leadinfo ;

    public LeadInfo__c getleadinfo(){

        if(leadVarId == null)
            leadinfo = [Select ID, Street_Address__c, City__c,Lead__r.name, CreatedDate from LeadInfo__c where Lead__c = :leadVarId order by CreatedDate desc limit 1];
        //system.debug('Lead name::'+leadinfo.lead__r.name);
        return leadinfo;
    }

    public void setleadinfo(){

    }
    public id leadVarId {
       get;set;
    }



    public lead ld {get;set;}



    public LeadInfocon(){

    }

}
```

What i am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: We can't help without some more information... What are you trying to do? What doesn't work and what have you tried?

Comment: I suggest to remove the 3dr line of code `public LeadInfo__c leadinfo ;` your variable and method name is same.. `public LeadInfo__c leadinfo ;`  and ` public LeadInfo__c getleadinfo(){` both will be accessible in VF page using `{!leadinfo}` ... I think is making conflict

Comment: Try to call the getleadinfo() method from leadVarId  get method. Parameter will not me resolved at the moment where you are referring now.

Comment: from Email template the leadid is not getting passed to component

Comment: when sending to leads, `relatedToType=` is not required and may be the source of your issue.